# Install APK on Phone Memory will Affect Performance of Phone?

Tags: android, performance

I am working on theme in `Android`. By default the themes are installed on `Phone's internal` Memory. On installing many themes the memory occupied by themes will increase. Will this be affecting the performance of Device or RAM of Device. To avoid this I am thinking to install all theme APKs on SD card will this help me.

Answer (score 0):

The occupation degree of the internal memory, doesn't affect the performance of the phone as long as it's not nearly full. If your themes are not very big, there is no reason to move them on the SD Card.